# Performance issue for large tables

Tags: mysql, performance

I am working on a website where users perform different tasks. Each activity of a user is recorded in a table. For performance measures, the records of over 12 months are moved to another table. But the records have reached over 40 million for one table and 20 million for another.

The users are divided into 3 groups.

1. Who clicked within 90 days
2. Who clicked within 180 days
3. Who did not click for over 180 days

I run a cron job which updates the groups of these users based on above checks.

The problem now is that the data is large, and sometimes the cron job crashes. To mention here, the date column of the table is **not indexed** and I am afraid of indexing it now as it might crash the table and I might not be able to recover it.

Any solutions on what should be done to it? And how can I cater this issue for future as the records would further increase by the end of this year.

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE users
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT users.userid, max(b.click_date ) click_date
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT userid, max( clickdate ) click_date
            FROM user_clicks
            WHERE DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , clickdate ) > 180
            GROUP BY userid
            UNION
            SELECT unique_code userid, max( clickdate ) click_date
            FROM user_clicks_archived
            WHERE DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , clickdate ) > 180
            GROUP BY unique_code    

        )b ON users.userid = b.userid
        WHERE users.status =1
        GROUP BY users.userid

    ) FINAL_CLICKS on FINAL_CLICKS.userid = users.userid
SET users.groupid = '3'
```

Comment: *I am afraid of indexing it now as it might crash the table and I might not be able to recover it*...if you're backing up your data regularly, this won't be an issue.

Comment: The clicks are happening so fast. I am backing it up though but still I have a risk of missing out important clicks in case there is an issue. Moreover, could you also please tell any other measures I can take?

Comment: is it possible for you to split these tables into three tables? (user with below 90) and (user from 90 to 180) and (user above 180). scenario would be, user entry will be created in below 90 table first and then probably every night (or whenever your load is minimum on system) run a cron job to update and move the records into next level table. And run your update query on separate tables simultaneously. If this is not possible then at your lowest load hour take snapshot of DB and apply index on date and try again.

Comment: Just tip try this `DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , clickdate ) > 180` change to this `clickdate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ),INTERVAL -180 DAY)`, of course index on clickdate should increase performance

Comment: @Nachiket Thanks, your idea is good but it still does not cater the table filling issue. I will still be facing the bottleneck in a few years. Justin thanks for your tip. I will try with this and will see if it makes any changes.

Answer (score 1):

You *should* index it, after ensuring it's backed up if you're really worried (you can schedule down-time for this if you're really paranoid). Even forty million rows is a relatively small table in DB land but not if you're frequently doing full table scans on it.

---

Alternatively, there appears to be a disconnect between your business requirements and what was delivered.

If the only thing you need to know<sup>(a)</sup> is in which of those three groups a user falls, storing every event is a massive waste of resources.

You could just store the last time each user clicked and then use a query to act on that, something along the lines of (SQL pseudo-code):

```
select username from users where datediff (now, lastclick) > 180 days
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> There may be *other* valid reasons to store every event. If so, ignore this advice. But you should still design your tables for efficiency, and that means suitable indexes.

Comment: I don't just use it for groups purpose but to show a log to user for his activities. Alright, I will dive into this index thing for the date column. But my other fear is the bottleneck of the table. In matter of a few months or years my table would be filled up. What should I do about this? Manually creating archive tables is a headache.

Comment: @Raja, if doing it manually is a pain, you _automate_ it. Some DBMS' can automatically transfer records based on age, or partition up front so you don't have to. Whether MySQL can do that, I have no idea.

Comment: Yes, MySQL does support partitioning. And I was expecting someone to convince me over it. Thanks for your idea. I will keep this topic open for now so someone else who's a MySQL geek might discuss partitioning.